# clang-format: force parameters to one-line-each even if the statement does NOT overflow

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is there any options of clang format enforcing one parameter per line even if the statement does NOT overflow? For example,

```
int add(int a,
        int b,
        int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

I have tried every related option on https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: Emphasis: The key point is "parameter ALWAYS one per line", even if they are short enough to be fit in one line!

Comment: Not possible :-(

Comment: As for as I known, Clion has this option "Wrap always" in Function declaration parameters. This is exactly what I need!